# ListItem values changed when creating subsite from template

Tags: 2013, content-type, site-template, list-item

I have a problem where i have a template generated through "save site as template". With this template I want to create a subsite to a sitecollection. All is fine to the point when I look a list in the newly created site. All ListItems but three have the wrong contenttype.

The ContentTypes are all located on the list itself.

I haven't found any useful information on the internet regarding this problem.

If there is anyone with useful information regarding this problem please share!